# Objective-C in Linux - compiler errors

Tags: objective-c, linux

Learning objective c on linux but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

```
#import <objc/Object.h>
#import <stdio.h>

@interface Person : Object {
    @private char *name;
}
@property (readwrite, assign, nonatomic) char *name;
+ (Person *)alloc;
- (id)init;
- (id)initWithName;
- (void)sayHello;
@end

@implementation Person
@synthesize name;
+ (Person *)alloc {
    Person *a = [super alloc];
    return a;
}
- (id)init {
    self = [self initWithName:"Gert"];
    return self;
}
- (id)initWithName:(char *)name{
    if (self = [super init]){
        self.name=name;
    }
    return self;
}
- (void)sayHello {
    printf("Hello, my name is %s!\n", self.name);
}
@end

int main() {
    Person *brad = [[Person alloc] init];
    brad.name = "Brad";
    [brad sayHello];
    Person *tom = [[Person alloc] init];
    tom.name = "Tom";
    [tom sayHello];
}
```

compiler output:

```
main2.m:18:24: error: class method '+alloc' not found (return type defaults to
      'id') [-Werror,-Wobjc-method-access]
    Person *a = [super alloc];
                       ^~~~~
main2.m:26:23: error: 'Object' may not respond to 'init' [-Werror]
    if (self = [super init]){
                ~~~~~ ^
main2.m:27:19: error: local declaration of 'name' hides instance variable
      [-Werror,-Wshadow-ivar]
        self.name=name;
                  ^
main2.m:15:17: error: method definition for 'initWithName' not found
      [-Werror,-Wincomplete-implementation]
@implementation Person
                ^
main2.m:11:1: note: method 'initWithName' declared here
- (id)initWithName;
^
```

Comment: Can't help you with the first two since I've only used obj-C on iOS.  You might be able to fix the 27:19 error by removing the `@synthesize` line.  If not, your options are to change it to `@synthesize name = _name;`, or change the name of the argument in the `initWithName` method.  The 15:17 and 11:1 errors are due to a mismatch between the declaration and definition of the `initWithName` method.  On line 11, you need to declare that method as `- (id)initWithName:(char *)name;`

Comment: main2.m:16:13: error: synthesized property 'name' must either be named the same
      as a compatible instance variable or must explicitly name an instance
      variable
@synthesize name=_name;

Comment: Ok, they've improved this on iOS.  I suggest just changing the `initWithName` method to `- (id)initWithName:(char *)initialName` to avoid the conflict.

Comment: thanks now I only have the first 2 errors left :)